# Do I need to keep the reference to a Disposable

Tags: java, project-reactor

If I have a long running (it takes a long time until it emits its only signal) `Mono` and I subscribe to it, I get a `Disposable` as a return value. Do I have to keep a reference to the `Disposable` instance somewhere in order for the `Mono` to be able to finish its work? If I do not have to store the `Disposable` instance who keeps the reference to the subscription alive and how come it is not accidentally garbage collected?

I ask because I am coming from the RxSwift and iOS world where one would store such `Disposable` instances and at some point clean up those disposables. The subscribing class would store the instance of the disposable and on `deinit` call `cancel` on the `Disposable`.

Comment: In a word: No, not unless you want some way of cancelling the subscription before it completes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use it, you won't need to hold the reference.

The reactor concept is very similar to threading. When you start a thread, it will do its job and exit after that (even if you do not hold the reference to it). Of course it can throw exception or be killed if it is a deamon thread and all non deamon thread are exited (so the program was finished).

While your application is alive, it isn't problem not holding the reference, since reactor stream is like some bunch of method calls which running on the caller or different thread and the thread's stack will hold all necessary references.

When you create a stream, default it will run on the caller thread.
For example here it will print all numbers and then exit the program. The stream will emmit items on the main thread (the caller) so the main cannot exit until the stream running:

```
fun main() {
    Flux.just(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).doOnNext { println(it) }.subscribe()
}
```

When you change emitter thread, and it is a deamon thread, the application will exit instantly, because it emmits the items on different thread than main and nothing stop main from exiting. Nothing will be printed.

```
fun main() {
    Flux.just(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
        .doOnNext { println(it) }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
        .subscribe()
}
```

But if you use nondeamon, it will print the numbers:

```
val executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1) {
    val thread = Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread(it)
    thread.isDaemon = false
    thread
}

fun main() {
    Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
        .doOnNext { println(it) }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.fromExecutorService(executorService))
        //.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
        .subscribe()
    println("After subscribe")
    //The executorService should be shut down here
}
```

When you use webserver (like netty), it will keep the application running, so reactive streams can operates until the server will be shut down.

Note that this is a simplification of reactor. I suppose you to read the documentation and java threading to fully understand this topic.